# Mesh generation from PointCloud?

Tags: python, modeling, mesh, blender-internal-render-engine

The figure below is the pointcloud imported as .ply file into blender. [image: PointCloud]

However, I would like to perform triangulation on it to produce the surface as seen in picture below(Accomplished using ballpivoting surface reconstruction and poisson disk sampling in MeshLab). [image: Traingulation]

Is there a way to perform triangulation on blender.
(PS: The purpose is to be able to select each faces/vertices individually to automate further.)

Edit: Question: Is it possible to select the vertex/faces programmatically post triangulation? if so, please explain how?

Answer (score 1):

Figured out that the existing blender addon given [here](https://blenderartists.org/t/a-script-to-skin-a-point-cloud-for-blender-2-6x-or-later/529168) serves the purpose if the objective is just to triangulate in blender. [image]

However, the question of programmatically selecting the vertex and (or) faces is still open. If any body has any idea on this topic please do throw some light.

Comment: I think this addon is outdated? It does not work with Blender 3.6. Maybe MeshLab is a better addon to use.