# How to Generate surface from points

Tags: mesh, vertices, point-clouds

[image][image]

Hi Guys,

I have a set of points in 3D. How can I convert this into a surface ?

Comment: You can use [meshlab](http://www.meshlab.net/) to turn the pointcloud into a mesh. There is a filter called: *Poisson Surface Reconstruction*. The paper can be found here: http://hhoppe.com/poissonrecon.pdf

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mesh generation from PointCloud?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/111141/mesh-generation-from-pointcloud) or [Wrapping a mesh around point cloud with cavities](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7028/wrapping-a-mesh-around-point-cloud-with-cavities)

Answer (score 2):

A vertice-only cluster is to be wrapped in a 'skin'.  The cluster has no edges or faces, just a host of vertices on their own.

[image]

A plane was laid on top that was large enough to accomodate the vertice cluster in the X/Y axis' and raised to be comfortably above the highest peak in the cluster.

It was then subdivided with at least as many subdivision/vertices as the vertice cluster.  I subdivided all four edges with the value of 100.  If that's not enough subdivide all four edges by 2 (or more), then again by 100 to produce 200 x 200.

Both the subdivided plane and the vertice cluster have their respective 'scale'  "Applied" with CTL-A.

The Shrinkwrap Modifier was used on the plane to in essence, lay a 'skin' over the cluster, citing the cluster as the target and  choosing "Nearest Vertex" option.

[image]

The settings can be tweaked to suit and  once satisfied, the modifier can be 'Applied' to convert the generated skin into hard mesh.

This is then 'smoothed' in the tools panel which can still leave it a trifle 'blocky' so the "Smooth" modifier was also used, it's own settings tweaked to give the final result.  That modifier was also 'Applied', leaving the shape in it's finally meshed form.

Not sure if this is exactly what you're seeking, but it should be a start at least.

[image]

Comment: This solution has very limited application to only flat terrain like meshes.