# how to combine vertices into a surface

Tags: 3d-view, point-clouds

I have an array of vertices from the .obj file. I transferred it to a blender . BUT I can't create the surface.

how to combine points into a single surface ??

[image]
[image]

Comment: This might help - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/167866/how-to-generate-surface-from-points/167888#167888

Answer (score 9):

This is not any old point-cloud.. working on the assumption the points are on a rectangular grid of rectangles, in the XY of its own object space, with Z as height, here's a GN modifier to derive a quad surface from it:

[image]

Just bureaucracy really, nothing exciting, getting counts and positions from the point-grid, as shown: (The mystery 'SZ0' node is  *Geometry > Transform*> scale Z to 0.)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Cool! A new use for Geo Nodes... turning junk mesh data into usable mesh data. :-)

Answer (score 5):

A vertex is just a single point in Blender. It won't be rendered.

An edge is just connection between two points in vertex. It won't be rendered.

A face is the connection of multiple edges, it will be rendered.

Additional infos:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/modeling/meshes/structure.html

So i think you need more information than just "points". You need edges information (which points should be connected) and you need face information (which edges are used to build a face).

But yes, if your "points" are just heights of course you could convert them into a surface, but you didn't write that explicitely.

Answer (score 1):

Made a quick video tutorial related to @Edgel3D comment:
(Use shrinkwrap modifier)
[Verteces to Surface](https://youtu.be/5MlWkPxlel4)