# Create a plane from contour lines

Tags: height-map

I'm new to Blender and am experimenting using it to design a landscaping project. I have a DXF file with contour lines for the land and have managed to import these into Blender. My aim is to have a full surface that reflects the site, and where I can start manipulating the slope and adding shapes onto it.

I now have a series of lines with heights, but that are not connected to each other and don't have an edge around them. After a long time trying to just join the edges using a combination of selecting them and choosing "Connect vertex path" or "Merge vertices > at center" (when connect didn't work) I thought maybe I'd be able to create a plane from it. However this only created small patches of planes so I'm guessing I've done something wrong. I was thinking as a next option I could just create a plane of the same size underneath it and manually drag each point up to match a point on one of the contour lines. This would probably take quite a while - is there any better option out there?

[image: view of imported lines]

Comment: Hello :). This is called *Point Cloud Skinning*. Here are some threads covering this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/167866/, https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7028/, https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/111141/

Comment: Apart from the point cloud skinning (which is not built into Blender well), have you tried simply selecting all [A], making a face [F] and triangulating [Ctrl T] ?

Comment: @Leander I tried creating a face, but it doesn't work well as it results in just a few spots with faces (like in the image I posted). I was trying to use the point cloud skinning but I'm using 2.82 and I don't see the "Point cloud skinning" option in the scene panel as I would expect from the documentation for the add-on. Maybe it's not compatible with this version?

Comment: I tried shrinkwrap the method suggested [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/167866/how-to-generate-surface-from-points) and it seems to work pretty well. Thanks @JachymMichal !