How to add color to a black & white 3D laser scan (.wrl) file imported into blender?

I imported a 3d point cloud into blender .wrl file. The scan was without color just black and white. The image shows the point cloud, I want to add color to it, but not sure how I would do this.

Hello and welcome to BSE. When you have a point cloud, you basically only have a mesh of vertices. There are no faces but you need mesh with faces to put "color" or material to it. To convert a point cloud to a mesh with faces you could use this strategy: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/301218/how-can-i-convert-a-complex-point-cloud-to-mesh

Cool, Yes this will work, thank you.
